# Create imageview dynamically in getview method of custom image adapter

Tags: android-imageview

I want to create an imageview dynamically in the getview method of custom adapter to display downloaded image in the listview. But image is not displaying.

My piece of code is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageview = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_image, null);


            imageview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50));
            imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageview.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            convertView.setTag(imageview);

            progress.setVisibility(progress.VISIBLE);

            new DownloadTask().execute(images.get(position), imageview);                 
        }else{
            new DownloadTask().execute(images.get(position), imageview);            
            return convertView;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        iv.setImageBitmap(result);          

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i can not get your question properly untill you provide more code.
it is not described properly.
you have to describe it properly or show us log cat error,or the problem you are facing in this task!
and from the code i can say that you are using asynchronus task,so in asynchronus task there is so much important to publish progress after the task or when ever you want to update the UI use "publishProgress();".

also i am sharing some links which may help you in this!
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery/
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/11/asynctask-android-example-asynctask-in.html